# CSS transform and hover for button inside transformed element

Tags: css

I just do not understand what is going on. My HTML:

```
<div class='quote_post'>
    <div class='quote_hover'>
        <div class='action_button'>
            <a href='<?php the_permalink() ;?>'><span>Read More</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.quote_post{
    background:#f2f2f2;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
}
.quote_hover{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:10010;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0,280px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,280px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,280px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,280px);
     transform: translate(0,280px);
}
.quote_post:hover .quote_hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,220px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,220px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,220px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,220px);
     transform: translate(0,220px);
    opacity:1;
}
```

And what is my problem in here. Hover works. Element move from bottom with button inside it ... but ...

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink() ;?>'><span>Read More</span></a>

.action_button{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;  
}
.action_button a{
    position:relative;z-index:13000;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 12px 8px 12px;
    border:1px solid #bcbcbc;
}
```

This  tag often do not react ... I must few times try move mouse on it to get this link work.

What I do not see? I also try by jQuery with on('mouseenter') - and that same behavior

ANSWER - Works Good on FireFox and Safari. Doesn't work as it should on Chrome.

Comment: Can you add the full code, then lets have a look at.

Comment: Cannot replicate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rOxEdz

Comment: And I can ... When I many times move to hide and show hover ,sometimes <a> tag doesn't react on hover - Chrome bug? ... very often when transition do not end and I fast move second time on <a>

Comment: Yes, chrome is a entire bug.

Comment: OK, on FireFox and Safari works OK.

Comment: I must say that people in here with every day are more stupid ... who mark this as not programming question to close ? CSS and HTML are a medicine question? ...